# Parsing multiple JSON objects sent via Express client-side in C#

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm trying to Parse two objects sent via Express to my unity client into c# objects.

Here I am sending the search results of a mongoose.model.find

```
res.send({account: accountData, score: scoreData})
```

Over in my Unity client this is the function that grabs the data above from my node.js server. I recieve the information here as the [www.downloadHandler.text](http://www.downloadHandler.text)

```
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(hostURL + "Login", loginForm))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();


        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error Sending Login Detail: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            if (www.responseCode == 200)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

                thisUser = username;
                menu.LoginPassed();
                leaderboard.LoadPlayerScoreData(www.downloadHandler.text);


            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Login Unsuccessful. Reason: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for reference here is the output of the Debug.Log([www.downloadHandler.text](http://www.downloadHandler.text)) so we can see what we are working with:

```json
{
    "account":[
        {
            "_id":"62fc40709bc9c241c7f650cd",
            "username":"BaggyJ",
            "password":"12345",
            "email":"@hotmail",
            "hhs":0,
            "level":1,
            "xp":0,
            "currency":0,
            "premiumCurrency":0,
            "__v":0
        }
    ],
    "score":[
        {
            "_id":"62fb4efe6e3a942138405b3e",
            "username":"BaggyJ",
            "score":420,
            "__v":0
        }, // ...
    ]
}
```

Here I am recieving the information as intended, the account data contains the player account informaton and the score data is an array of the players best scores. So far so good!

The next step obviously, is to parse this information into a usable C# object. I attempted to do this in the same way I had previously accomplished in this project.

I will show you here the solution for this I'm using that does not work, and an example of the solution when it does work.

Firstly, what I have thats **not** working:

I created two C# serialized classes to represent the information.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DataPackage
{
    public string account;
    public string score;
}
```

And

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DataPackages
{
    public DataPackage[] dataPackages;
}
```

Finally, I use the JSON Utility function to parse the data string included above

```
  public DataPackages ParseData(string jsonText)
    {
        DataPackages dataPackages = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataPackages>("{\"dataPackages\":" + jsonText + "}");
        return dataPackages;
    }
```

If I attempt to use the above code the dataPackages.dataPackages object is always null.

The function is meant to result in an object with two strings, the first to represent the account data and the second to represent the score data.

These two string will then be parsed a second time into their final C# objects for use.

It is worth noting here that the parsing tools for account data and score data are built the same way and function as expected. I will include one below for reference:

```
 [System.Serializable]
public class ScorePacket
{
    public string username;
    public string score;
}


    [System.Serializable]
public class ScorePackets
{
    public ScorePacket[] scorePackets;
}


   public ScorePackets ParseScore(string jsonText)
    {
        ScorePackets scorePackets = JsonUtility.FromJson<ScorePackets>("{\"scorePackets\":" + jsonText + "}");
        return scorePackets;
    }
```

The above code will return an c# object where I can access its data as such: scorePackets.scorePackets[0].score

Any insight into why I cannot accomplish this with DataPackages would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

So I've gotten it a little closer but not quite.

I have replaced:

```
DataPackages dataPackages = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataPackages>("{\"dataPackages\":" + jsonText + "}");
```

With:

```
DataPackages dataPackages = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataPackages>("{\"dataPackages\":[" + jsonText + "]}");
```

This successfully creates a C# object with the correct fields HOWEVER both of these field are empty.

```
Debug.Log(dataPackages.dataPackages[0].score)
Debug.Log(dataPackages.dataPackages[0].account)
```

Both return empty strings.

**Edit#2**

We are getting so close I can taste it.

So in addition to the above changes I have also made the following change to my node.js server:

```
res.send({account: accountData.toString(), score: scoreData.toString()})
```

Now if I:

```
Debug.Log(dataPackages.dataPackages[0].score.ToString());
Debug.Log(dataPackages.dataPackages[0].account.ToString());
```

My output is:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

[object Object]
```

.ToString() failed to get the json text for these objects

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I needed to change the way I declared my DataPacket class from containing strings to containing object arrays.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DataPackage
{
   public AccountPacket[] account;
   public ScorePacket[] score;
}
```

Solved my problems